# Получить файл удаленно по маске!

Tags: php, изображения

Люди добрые, хочу просто получить удаленно файл по маске с сервера и сохранить к себе в папку.
Все, что перед ...small.jpg меняется каждые 3 дня, путь не меняется

```
$url = "http://somefile.ru/uploads/image/bnr/iuni17813small.jpg";
$dir = __DIR__ . "/subfolder";
$file = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents("/subfolder/my_superfile.jpg", $file);
```

А можно было бы сделать как-то так?

```
<img src="http://somefile.ru/uploads/image/bnr/[mask]small.jpg"
```

Большое спасибо! Главное, чтобы рабочий вариант.

Comment: Никак. протокол http позволяет работать только с полностью заданными именами файлов. Если конечно нет какого нибудь списка файлов из которого можно было бы получить требуемое имя

Comment: @Mike Очень жаль, что так есть:-(((((((